Getter method in matrix class not working properly
I'm trying to get this Getter method to return the assigned value in a matrix for a given row and column, and of course I set the return type as float.
But when I'm running a test function, I'm getting back the number as an int, i.e 1 instead of 1.0, which is making my code not working probably, here's my getter and setter
float Matrix::element(int row, int col) const {
    if (row < 0 || row > nRows || col < 0 || col > nCols) 
        throw out_of_range("Index out of range.");
    return data[row * nCols + col];
}


void Matrix::set_element(int row, int col, float val) {
    if (row < 0 || row > nRows || col < 0 || col > nCols) {
        cerr << "Error: index is out of range. " << endl;
        throw out_of_range("Index is out of range.");
    }
    data[row * nCols + col] = val;
}

and here is the test function
void test() {
  Matrix A(2, 2);
  A.set_element(1, 1, 1.0);
  A.set_element(1, 2, 2.0);
  A.set_element(2, 1, 3.0);
  A.set_element(2, 2, 4.0);
  Matrix B(2, 2);
  A.add(B);
  cout << A.element(1, 1);                      // This is printing 1 instead of 1.0
  if (almost_equal(A.element(1, 1), 1.0)
      && almost_equal(A.element(1, 2),  2.0)
      && almost_equal(A.element(2, 1),  3.0)
      && almost_equal(A.element(2, 2),  4.0)) {
    cerr << "Passed" << endl;;
  } else {
    cerr << "Failed" << endl;
    return;
  }
}

I clearly did something wrong but can't find where, a second eye might help!:)

The cout print format is seprate from the type of the value (which is indeed float as you expected). You can see this this minimal demo: godbolt. You can use <iomanip> to format the cout print output.

Coding tip: see all that duplicated code? Put it into a single function and call that function when you need to find an element: float& get(int row, int column) { /* validation */ return data[row*nCols + col); }. Then the setter and getter are much simpler: float Matrix::get_element(int row, int col) { return get(row, col); } and void Matrix::set_element(int row, int col, float val) { get(row, col) = val; }.

If your logic is not behaving as you expect, the issue lies elsewhere - the format of the cout print is unrelated to that (as I mentioned in my previous comment). Posting a [mre] will help us help you identify the problem.

Oh I see! Then my issue lies elsewhere, I will continue debugging, thank you guys!:)

What does Matrix look like?  Is a Matrix A(2, 2) a 3x3 matrix, so it's valid for 2,2?  (C++ uses cardinal offset which is 0-based and starts at 0.  Some other languages use ordinal index which is 1-based and starts at 1.  No one liked my compromise of having array access start at a[0.5].)

This code:
void Matrix::set_element(int row, int col, float val) {
    if (row < 0 || row > nRows || col < 0 || col > nCols) {
        cerr << "Error: index is out of range. " << endl;
        throw out_of_range("Index is out of range.");
    }
    data[row * nCols + col] = val;
}

last line assumes indexing form 0 to nRows - 1 (or nCols - 1),
but range checking is invalid. It accepts also index nRow.
Now assuming your data have size nRow * nCols your test code is leading to buffer overflow, since it is using indexes from 1. So this line:
A.set_element(2, 2, 4.0);

will buffer overflow and your earlier check in Matrix::set_element will not catch that.
So you have bug in production code (wrong checking of index ranges) and in test code.
